# AngularJS loading individual userProfiles

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS trying to create a small service as a student project.

I have a html5 template available under `http:.../profile.html`
This template is "**angularJS-friendly**" meaning that I can load any profile informating in my profile.html ( e.g. username with {{user.username}}, ...) from a **Rest service** providing me with a appropriate **json**

Now when I want to load `http:../profile/{usernameXYZ}` as in **PHP** `/profile.php?username=usernameXYZ`

How do I do this?

To be more specific: How do I create/load/??? individual profile pages with only one template in angularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add '[ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)' as a dependency in your app

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        //configure the routing rules here
        $routeProvider.when('/profile/:username/', {
            controller: 'PagesCtrl'
        });

        //routing DOESN'T work without html5Mode
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })
    .controller('PagesCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $route) {
        //If you want to use URL attributes before the website is loaded
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
            console.log($routeParams.username)
        });
    });
```

and now you will be able to navigate your app in this routes **http://...../profile/testUserName**

Comment: I think this does not solve my problem.
When calling the url: http://.../profile.php?=username=userXY
I get an individual User Profile.
I can do this for any user by changing the param in the url

.I want an equivalent with angularJs, but generate this from my /profile.html template

.I read about injecting the $scope using **ngRoute** ?

I want to be able to call an individual user profile with just an url

Comment: as I understood you want to specifed URL for user profiles ? for example /user/profile/USERID in your angularjs app ?

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you don't have any additional questions. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this. After I cut out ' $locationProvider' it works.
Thanks again.